# Missing Sun PKCS#11 Provider in lib/java.security

Tags: java, keystore

I am trying to configure to use HSM with java keytool and I need the " security.provider.7=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 " to work with it

Mine

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

Sample

```
 security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
    security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
    security.provider.3=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
    security.provider.4=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
    security.provider.5=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
    security.provider.6=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
    security.provider.7=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 C:\\Program
    Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_18\\jre\\lib\\security\\luna.cfg
    security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
    security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
    security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
```

I have java 1.8 JDK installed but still not appearing in the java security file.
How do I get those provider in?

Comment: please, how you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Config) state that after the classname should follow the path to a suitable configuration file (as per the sample), or that the provider should be manually instantiated and added to the `Security` class. It appears to be missing in your file.

Answer (score 0):

It is something you have to add it yourself. The `SunPKCS11` Provider class requires a configuration file which has the connection parameters to your HSM.

xThe most important attributes needed in the configuration file are `library` which points to the HSM manufacturer's dll/so file. `name` the name of the provider (can be any value) and `slot` the slot number in which the token is present or `slotListIndex` the index of the slot from the slot list available.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to respond but it will help for future developers.

I had same issue in my case, here are the steps to fix it.

**Steps1:** *You need to update the java.Security file which can be found under JRE ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security to include SunPKCS11 provider.

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.4=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.5=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.6=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.7=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.8=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.9=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
security.provider.10=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 ${your_cfg_filePath}/pkcs11_sdkdata.cfg
security.provider.11=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 /${your_cfg_filePath}/pkcs11.cfg
```

**Steps2:** make sure you have updated pkcs11.cfg and pkcs11_sdkdata.cfg files on given path which include your HSM key with nCiphers. Which includes the path of libcknfast.so files.

**Steps3:**  If we are putting the java.security file outside the JRE then we need to provide the below jvm args.**

```
 -Djava.security.properties==${java_security_filePath}/java.security\
 -DKEY_STORE=/${your_cfg_filePath}/pkcs11.cfg \
 -DKEY_LABEL={KEY_LABEL} \
 -DCRYPTO_LABEL={CRYPTO_LABEL} \
 -DKEY_STORE_SDK_DATA=${your_cfg_filepath}/pkcs11_sdkdata.cfg \
 -DKEY_LABEL_SDK_DATA={sdkData_Label}\
 -DCRYPTO_LABEL_SDK_DATA={crypto_sdkData_Label}
```

In your code you can use the like this

```
Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", provider);
```